# How can I update a DS.Model with response json from store.commit()?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Given the models:

```
Blog.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    tags:  DS.hasMany('Blog.Tag', { embedded: true })
});

Blog.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
    foo: DS.attr('string'),
    bar: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And the instance:

```
var myPost = Blog.Post.createRecord({ id: 45, title: 'Foo Bar' })
```

When I do `myPost.store.commit()` (via ember-data's DS.RESTAdapter) my server returns a list of automatically generated tags that should be applied to `myPost`.  Example response json:

```
{
  posts: [
    {
      id: 45,
      title: 'Foo Bar',
      tags: [
        { id: 1, foo: 'bar1' },
        { id: 2, foo: 'bar2' }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd expect that `myPost` would end up with the two tags as returned by the json, but I get this error instead:

```
Error: <DS.StateManager:ember448> could not respond to event invokeLifecycleCallbacks in state rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: clarified json to include ids per @MikeAski's comment. The example given is a simplified version of my actual case--the actual case does include tag ids.

Comment: Did you try to sideload the tags rather than embed them?

Comment: Something strange: your tags do not have ids. Looks wrong... Any Serializer missing for Tag model on the server?

Comment: @MikeAski I haven't tried sideloading the tags--I'll give that a shot and post how it turns out.  Updated the question to include tag ids; I left them out when boiling down the question into a simple case.

Comment: What version of ember-data are you using? Try adding your 'myPost' to a transaction and commit the transaction instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to 'mirror' relations between model's:

```
   Blog.Post = DS.Model.extend({
        title: DS.attr('string'),
        tags:  DS.hasMany('Blog.Tag', { embedded: always })
    });

    Blog.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
        foo: DS.attr('string'),
        bar: DS.attr('string'),
        post: DS.belongsTo('Blog.Post')
    });
```

Then you will need to add mappings to your adapter:

```
Blog.RESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();

    this.map('Blog.Post',{
      tag:{embedded:'always'},
    });
  }
});
```

And add post_id to Tag in your JSON.