# Nested Model [ember-1.0.0-rc.1 + ember.data-11]

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

**Question 1**
What's wrong in my concept of creating a nested model in ember-1.0.0-rc.1 + ember.data-11?

**Question 2**
With var line = App.Line.find() I should get the Line. How can I get the Andon or the Shift as Object, nested in a Line? Or only the color from Andon?

Here my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcRtu/2/).

```
App.Line = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    shifts: DS.hasMany('App.Shift'),
});

App.Shift = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),    
    // shift 1 <-> 1 shifts
    line: DS.belongsTo('App.Line'),
    //  one-to-one relationship between Shift and Andon
    andon: DS.belongsTo('App.Andon')
 });

 App.Andon = DS.Model.extend({
    //  one-to-one relationship between Shift and Andon 
    shift: DS.belongsTo('App.Shift')
 })
```

The Controller

```
 App.LinesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
     content: [],
 });

 App.linesController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    init: function(){

    var self = this;
    self.pushObject(

        App.Line.createRecord(
                        {
                        ...
                        shifts: [ 
                          App.Shift.createRecord(
                          {
                            andon:  App.Andon.createRecord({...})
                          }),
                          App.Shift.createRecord(
                          {
                            andon: App.Andon.createRecord({...})
                          }),

                        ]   
                    },
                   ],
                }
            ),      
        );  
    }, 
 });
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

concerning question 2:

i think you need to add a foreign key for every belongsTo, i.e. line_id and andon_id in Shift and shift_id in Andon, and then you'll need to create some serializers where you can embed/sideload associations. unfortunately, i'm only familiar with the activeModel serializers from rails, which can probably not be used in your case, but maybe the example in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532282/how-can-i-update-a-ds-model-with-response-json-from-store-commit) will help you.